# Perforce License Problem

Tags: perforce

We are moving our Perforce server to a Linux virtual machine. I can get the new Perforce server to start up without a license. When I copy our existing license file to the new server, all I get is:

```
Perforce server error:
    License file invalid.
    Support expired.
```

The IP address of the server is the same as in the license file. The support expiration is "2009/12/18". I downloaded a p4d server older than that date, but that didn't fix it either. I hope someone has some idea what's going on here, I am by no means a Perforce expert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Comment: Email support@perforce.com with the license file attached - they should be able to sort it out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vendors frequently will node-lock license files to a specific piece of hardware. In most of the cases I've seen, they will encode the machine's MAC address into the license file. I'm not certain if Perforce does this, but it's something you ought to look into.

If it **is** node locked, you can either request the Perforce send you a new license file for the MAC address of the new machine or alternatively you can manually set the new VM's MAC address to match that of the old server. Of course you should only do this if the old machine is being retired.

Answer (score 3):

Perforce locks the license to the IP address of the machine, if you submit a support request to [Perforce Support](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/support.html) they can issue you with a new license file within a couple of hours. We've migrated our p4 server a couple of times and have never had any (major) issues. If you don't pay for support there is nothing simple you can do to get around this, except possibly migrate the old IP address to the new machine.